# Alpha or numerically order localStorage getItem

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm successfully using .join() (thanks, [@twofivethreetwo](http://paperkilledrock.com/2010/05/html5-localstorage-part-one/)) to join multiple values to a single key for localStorage.

I'm also able to unpack those joined values and build a list, and make the item's key be the list item's ID.

What I can't figure out how to do is order that list items numerically or alphabetically based on the list item ID (I don't care if the key is a numeral or a letter).

How can I sort the list by the list item ID?

http://jsfiddle.net/natejones/bPsfQ/21/

Comment: Put them in an array and use the native JavaScript Array `.sort()`. You can pass `.sort()` a function to do the element-to-element comparisons.

Comment: I neglected to mention that the getItem would happen on another page.

Comment: How does the list get from one page to the next?

Comment: @Pointy localStorage setItem is on page 1, and the localStorage getItem is on page 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I neglected to mention that the getItem would happen on another page. I ended up including the [TinySort](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/) plugin.

```
$.tinysort.defaults.attr = 'class';
$('ul#itinerary>li').tsort();
```

Answer (score 1):

Collect all IDs in separate array, sort it with `sort()` and then in your `for` loop retrieve `itemKey` from this array, not from `localStorage` keys.